# Change the default Start and End Time for new Events

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

We are using a SharePoint team calendar for vacation form approvals. The default values for new events Start Time and End Time defaults to the next full hour, example **`5:00 PM to 6:00 PM`**, when entering a new item at **`4:44 PM`**.

Is it possible to set the default value for the start time to **`8:00 AM`** and end time to **`5:00 PM`**, but still keep the current, today's date?

We are using SharePoint 2010. I was able to find [this](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/), but it does not provide the solution I was hoping for + doesn't work for modal windows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable modal windows using `List settings > Advanced Settings > Launch Forms in a dialog = No`

The JavaScript given in the ["Setting a default duration for new SharePoint Calendar Events"](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/) post (I wrote it by the way!) can be easily modified to 8am / 5pm by anyone who's familiar with JavaScript.

Remove Lines 22 to 41 and add this after line 21

```
cboStartHours.val("08:");
cboEndHoursHours.val("17:");
```

*(Might be slightly different if depending on your regional settings look at the html source to see what  values are)*

Alternatively

- you can create your own "New" form using Visual Studio or SharePoint designer.
- You can force the "All Day Event" flag (still problem with Modal dlg boxes though) - http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-to-the-rescue-automate-all-day-event.aspx
- You can create a custom list that just has a start/end date rather than start/end date/time

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered using updating the default columns to include for their default values a calculated value as per the example Today + 0.33336 (08:00 AM) and Today + 0.70839 (17:00).

Alternatively, did you already calendar settings in your Regional Settings for the particular subsite to match your settings?

Comment: Marius - Thanks for your reply. No luck with the Regional Settings - The newform.aspx for the new calendar event still defaults to the next full hour, even after changing the regional settings (I didn't expect a change, as this setting is used for the calendar display, not the newform.aspx display, right?). I am not certain that you can configure the 'Start Time' and 'End Time' for the newform.aspx for the calendar event - Could you elaborate how to? I am really looking on how to modify the column that will default to the next full how in the newform.aspx. Thanks again, Chris.

Comment: I meant the actual columns of in the Calendar list.

Comment: You can't add in "Default Value" settings for Start/End time in Calendar Lists.